# Why I could not remove a model from a Backbone collection?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

When I try to remove a model from a collection, I get an error:

```
Cannot read property 'removed' of undefined
```

If I click two times, it works.

```js
var PhoneFormItemView = Marionette.View.extend({
  className: 'row',
  template: _.template('<div><input type="text" value="<%- type %>"><input type="text" value="<%- local_number %>"></div><button type="button" class="remove_phone_number-btn">Remove</button>'),
  triggers: {
    'click .remove_phone_number-btn': 'remove:item'
  }
});
var PhoneFormListView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
  className: 'phone-form-item',
  childView: PhoneFormItemView,
  onChildviewRemoveItem: function(childView) {
    this.collection.remove(childView.model);
    this.render();
  }
});

var phoneNumberView = Marionette.View.extend({
  el: '#phone-number',
  template: _.template('<div id="phone-number-region">asd</div>'),
  regions: {
    phoneNumberRegion: {
      el: '#phone-number-region'
    }
  },
  onRender: function() {
    var ModelPhoneNumber = Backbone.Model.extend();
    var CollectionPhoneNumber = Backbone.Collection.extend({
      model: ModelPhoneNumber
    });
    this.collectionPhoneNumber = new CollectionPhoneNumber();
    this.collectionPhoneNumber.add({
      type: 'bussines',
      country_code: 12,
      carrier_code: 34,
      local_number: 56789,
      extension: 444
    });
    this.collectionPhoneNumber.add({
      type: 'personal',
      country_code: 10,
      carrier_code: 20,
      local_number: 987564,
      extension: 23
    });
    this.showChildView('phoneNumberRegion', new PhoneFormListView({
      collection: this.collectionPhoneNumber
    }));
  }
});

var view = new phoneNumberView().render();
```

```html
<div id="phone-number"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.2.3/backbone-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.radio/2.0.0/backbone.radio.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.marionette/3.2.0/backbone.marionette.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If I click two times, it works. :/

Answer (score 2):

With  Backbone 1.3.3 it works.

From the [Marionette 3.2.0 readme](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/tree/v3.2.0):

> Compatibility and Requirements
>
> MarionetteJS currently works with the following libraries:
>
> - jQuery v1.8+
> - Underscore v1.8.3
> - Backbone v1.3.3
> - Backbone.Radio v2.0.0+

From the Backbone [changelog](http://backbonejs.org/#changelog):

> 1.3.3 — Apr. 5, 2016
>
> [...]
>
> - Added options.changes to Collection "update" event which includes added, merged, and removed models.
>
> [...]

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you can achieve this within your `PhoneFormItemView`. You can just create an event on click of `.remove_phone_number-btn` by using the `destroy` method of the model, as explained in the below code:

```
var PhoneFormItemView = Marionette.View.extend({
  className: 'row',
  template: _.template('<div><input type="text" value="<%- type %>"><input type="text" value="<%- local_number %>"></div><button type="button" class="remove_phone_number-btn">Remove</button>'),
  events: {
    'click .remove_phone_number-btn': 'removePhoneNumberHandler'
  },
  removePhoneNumberHandler: function() {
      this.model.trigger('destroy', this.model);
  }
});
var PhoneFormListView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
  className: 'phone-form-item',
  childView: PhoneFormItemView
});
```

The reason of using `this.model.trigger('destroy', this.model);` and NOT `this.model.destroy();` is that the later will send a server call to remove the model even from the server, while the former will delete the model from within the collection and remove that `PhoneFormItemView` from the DOM and update the collection.

Comment: The issue is solely what was explained [in this earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45245720). Once, the version problem is fixed, then the OPs code works just fine.

Comment: Yes correct. It surely is a version problem. I just gave an alternative as to how it could be achieved as the current code wouldn't function as per expectation because of the version issue.

Comment: Er... You're presenting this as an *alternative* to fixing the version problem? Marionette 3.2.0 *requires* Backbone 1.3.3 or higher. The only valid solution is to fix *that*. Don't go into workarounds that will make the OP's specific code not trigger an error when an incorrect version of Backbone is used which *may* work fine until inevitably *another* case causes a crash due to using the incorrect version of Backbone. That's a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: No I am not. I am just giving an alternative how to achieve deleting of an item from its collection.